# Python closure, local variable scope error

Tags: python, closures

My function throw me with the `local variable 'pt' referenced before assignment` error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/solesschong/Workspace/PenPal/python/main.py", line 126, in callback
    ind = (i+pt) % n
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pt' referenced before assignment
```

the code is as follows

```
def get_audio_callback(pt):

    def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):

        for i in range(frame_count):
            ind = (i+pt) % n

        return (a, b)

    return callback
```

and in global scope,

```
pt = 0
stream = p.open(stream_callback=get_audio_callback(pt))
```

I cannot figure out why the error occurs, since I've checked with some examples on closure and find no difference.

## Edit

The reason why you cannot reproduce the error might because of the over-simplify, as mentioned by @Martijn Pieters.
Hence the original code.

Further I've solved this problem by passing by reference, plz see my own answer.

```
"""
Sound API
"""
def get_audio_callback(pt):

    def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
        """
        This is the callback function for sound API
        In each call, synthesized data is dumpped into the sound buffer
        """        

        wave = np.ndarray((frame_count, 2))
        for i in range(frame_count):
            ind = (i+pt) % n
            wave[i,0] = float(x[ind]) * 2
            wave[i,1] = float(y[ind]) * 2
        pt = pt + frame_count

        return (encode(wave), pyaudio.paContinue)

    return callback


p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
pt = 0

stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                channels=2,
                rate=RATE,
                output=True,
                stream_callback=get_audio_callback(pt))
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. What is the full traceback?

Comment: You probably over-simplified. Is **any other code** in the `callback()` nested function touching upon `pt` in some way?

Comment: Is `pt` to be altered *at a global level* when you assign `pt = pt + frame_count`? Or should it be updated at the `get_audio_callback` level? There seems little point in updating `pt` at all, otherwise, you are not doing anything with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code *assigns to `pt`* in `callback`; Python determines the scope of a name at compile time and assignment makes this a local name.

```
pt = pt + frame_count
```

Unless you tell Python otherwise, that is. In Python 2, you can only mark a name explicitly as a `global` instead, you need Python 3 to be able to use the `nonlocal` keyword:

```
def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    """
    This is the callback function for sound API
    In each call, synthesized data is dumpped into the sound buffer
    """        

    nonlocal pt

    wave = np.ndarray((frame_count, 2))
    for i in range(frame_count):
        ind = (i+pt) % n
        wave[i,0] = float(x[ind]) * 2
        wave[i,1] = float(y[ind]) * 2
    pt = pt + frame_count

    return (encode(wave), pyaudio.paContinue)
```

With the `nonlocal pt` line Python is explicitly told not to treat `pt` as a local name but to take it from the enclosing scope of `get_audio_callback` instead.

In Python 2, you can just create a local that takes its value from the closure:

```
def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    """
    This is the callback function for sound API
    In each call, synthesized data is dumpped into the sound buffer
    """        

    pt_local = pt

    wave = np.ndarray((frame_count, 2))
    for i in range(frame_count):
        ind = (i+pt_local) % n
        wave[i,0] = float(x[ind]) * 2
        wave[i,1] = float(y[ind]) * 2
    pt_local = pt_local + frame_count

    return (encode(wave), pyaudio.paContinue)
```

because your enclosing `get_audio_callback` scope doesn't appear to use `pt` *anyway* and won't need access to the updated `pt_local` value.

If you do need `pt` to update at the `get_audio_callback` scope (if, say, `callback` is called multiple times and you need `pt` to be updated from call to call), you need to avoid using `pt` as a local inside the `callback` function altogether.

One effective work-around for that is to wrap the value in a mutable object or assign it as a mutable attribute somewhere that both the enclosing scope and the local scope can access it without it ever being seen as a local assignment. Setting an attribute on the `callback` function is a good way to do that:

```
def get_audio_callback(pt):

    def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
        """
        This is the callback function for sound API
        In each call, synthesized data is dumpped into the sound buffer
        """        

        wave = np.ndarray((frame_count, 2))
        for i in range(frame_count):
            ind = (i+callback.pt) % n
            wave[i,0] = float(x[ind]) * 2
            wave[i,1] = float(y[ind]) * 2
        callback.pt = callback.pt + frame_count

        return (encode(wave), pyaudio.paContinue)

    callback.pt = pt

    return callback
```

Here `callback.pt` is no longer a local name; it is an attribute on the `callback` function object instead.

Comment: You are perfect on answering this. And my workaround works because `pt = pt_ref[0]` actually takes value from closure. And no matter if it is `pt = pt_ref` or `pt = pt_ref[0]`

Comment: Exactly; but if you want `pt` to act as a closure (persisting between calls to `callback`) then the 'assign a local from the closure' is not going to work as the closure value is never going to be updated.

Comment: However the assigned local variable `pt` is indeed persisting. I'm not a pro in python and I haven't realized it weird before you mentioned it.

Comment: Do you assign back to `pt_ref[0]` at any point? Because then you are using the `pt_ref` list as a closure (never assign directly to the `pt_ref` name itself, only to its *indices*) in the same way I used the function attribute.

Comment: I'm afraid no assigning back. You can see the full code in [my Github repo](https://github.com/SolessChong/PenPal/blob/master/main.py)

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a problem about 'reference'

I changed my code into passing `pt` by variable, and it worked out fine.

```
pt = [0]

def get_audio_callback(pt_ref):

    def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):

        pt = pt_ref[0]

        for i in range(frame_count):
            ind = (i+pt) % n

        return (a, b)

    return callback
```

Comment: This just means you were doing something else with `pt` elsewhere in your callback *as well*. Your work-around may or may not be a good idea, but you haven't given us enough context to help with that.

Comment: Plz see my update in the question. I'm also curious about why the problem occurs and why my work around helps.

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?