# Local variable closure access inside a flask routed function

Tags: python, flask

I am using Flask 0.10 with Python 2.7 in a rest api.

I have a problem, I can't access read only variables declared before the closures in my functions.

It seems that @app.route decorator hides the variable someway because this work in a normal Python function.

```
@app.route('/orders', methods=['POST'])
@app.route('/orders/<int:order_id>', methods=['GET'])
def order(order_id=None):
    var = 1

    def post():
        print var
        var = None

    def get():
        print var
        var = None

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return get()
    else:
        return post()
```

It does not matter if I use GET or POST, I get:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'var' referenced before assignment

I know that I could pass "var" to the closure as a parameter but I have a bunch of shared variables and I am curious about why this happens anyway.

So, Why this happens and could you suggest a workaround? Thank you.

Edited: It seems to be related with the reasignation inside the function.

Comment: The code you posted *works*; but you are **asigning** in the *real* versions of those nested functions.

Comment: There is nothing special about Flask routing here otherwise. The `@app.route` decorator registers your view and returns the function un-altered.

Comment: You made *exactly the same mistake* as the OP of this post made: [Python closure, local variable scope error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23170754). In simplifying your code you removed the actual error.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I oversimplified the example :-(, I edited the question.

Comment: I voted the question to be closed myself because It is answered on the linked question, It seems I can't accept my own answer to close it and SO recommends me not to delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, It seems that I can't assign a closure variable afterwards operating with it.

In this case "print var" before local "var" assignment.

I miss nonlocal keyword from Python 3.